# sticker extension CFBundleVersion mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage-extension

NOT A DUPLICATE (see more below).

ItunesConnect gives me a warning with :

```
appex does not match the CFBundleVersion
```

It seems the error is related purely to the appex which seems to be a compiled version of my sticker extension.

Both targets (app and stickers) obviously have the same CFBundleVersion (both in plist and in target > general > build).

The culprit is the plist inside the .appex file (can see it with show package contents), i don't understand why it is different from the one used by the target.

From what i found it seems when archiving xcode creates a new .app file that will be only in the archive thus creating a new plist file but apparently some things in the appex file are not updated.

What are the possible options to fix this permanently ? I modified the value inside the file but i am not sure it will stick.

Answer (score 0):

So if any of you guys uses a build script to bump your CFBundleVersion make sure to place it before the Copy Bundle Ressources phase.